# automapper incomplete documentation

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I am looking for a documentation for automapper for c#.
On their site the documentation is incomplete (as I can see).
Example UseDestinationValue is not documented. Also there are other options that are not documented and explained.
Where I can find more comprehensive explanation of the automapper options (example UseDestinationValue and others) ?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such - it is a open source project and developers usually hate writing documentation :) The way I do get to know an open source project is looking at its unit tests - if project is well written, its unit tests are quite good documentation :)

Comment: I think you are right. I will take a look in the code and unit tests!

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow is a good place, otherwise, Google is your friend! ;-)

Concerning `UseDestinationValue()`, Jimmy Bogard says [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/automapper-users/uMuWCLFudGo/AiXPEaAvCEgJ):

> Ignore() will not map that member, nor any child members.  UseDestinationValue will leave the existing value there, but will continue mapping any other child members.  For example, UseDestinationValue on a collection type will leave things like the collection reference there, but will then fill the collection with values.  With a complex type, it will leave the reference as is, but then fill in the values.